# Pygame Freezes on Exit/Quit

Tags: python, pygame

I have done research about this problem, on internet, but there was no solution for my case... The window freezes when i try to close it with (X) button.
And as I said I haven't came across any solution on other posts, so I came here to ask for help. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame
# initialize
pygame.init()
# colors 
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)

# window size
w_size = [700,500]
main_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(w_size)
# Window info
pygame.display.set_caption("Cancer Cell")

# manage screen update time
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

#background image
bg_img = pygame.image.load("/img/bg_img.png").convert()

# Main loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    # GAME LOGIC - BEGINNING


    # -------- DRAWINGS - BEGINNING --------
    main_screen.blit(bg_img, [0,0])
    # -------- DRAWINGS - END ----------


    # update screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20) # 20 FPS limit for loop.

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the IDLE is what was causing the problem...
I tried to run the code from commandline and it worked perfectly!

The IDLE that I (was) using is called Wing101.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work perfectly well on my platform.
My platform:
Scientific Linux 7 (RHEL 7)
Python: 3.4.3
Pygame Version: 1.9.2b8
Window Manager: Gnome3

There is also probably bug in your code.
The "/img/bg_img.png" suggest absolute path, it possible, but very uncommon :).

Comment: If the file path to image would have been wrong, he would have seen the error `pygame.error: Couldn't open /img/bg_img.png`

Comment: `The "/img/bg_img.png" suggest absolute path` - I have the full path on my computer/editor, just removed it on here.

Mac - OSX El Capitan 10.11.6, Python 2.7.10, Pygame 1.9.1

Comment: You can try also 
 os._exit(0) instead of pygame.quit().

Answer (score 0):

Works pretty nicely for me. See the demo below:

[image]

Comment: I am on a MAC 10.11.6 - Python 2.7.10 - PyGame 1.9.1
Do I need to use Python 3 ? or..

Comment: I am using python 2.7 . Your code works pretty well for me. Try to debug if the event is captured or not. And if it is, then try adding `sys.exit()` instead of `pygame.quit()`

Comment: It works perfectly when I run in Debug mode and nothing is captured.

Comment: What are you using to compile your code with ? 
I use Wing101

Comment: Wing101 seems like an IDE. I just pass the code directly to the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Not only does your code work as expected on linux Mate 17, python 2.7.6 but it also works with `sys.exit()` instead of `pygame.quit()` or nothing at all i.e. no `sys.exit()` or `pygame.quit()`

Comment: So I tried to run another application (made by Pygame itself - an example game... ) It did work perfectly, but when I ran with the IDLE it gave errors... So Im wondering if its the fault of the IDLE ?

Comment: run your application from the command line and find out, it looks that way.

Comment: Im actually gonna bang my head on the wall for not using terminal in the first place... :D